# Why do we not write main() within class in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Why kotlin does not allow main() function within class just like Java? Why this is allowed outside of the class? Is not it violating OOP principle? I am puzzled!

```
class Person ( var name : String, var age : Int) {
    // putting main here
    fun main(args : Array<String>) {
        val person = Person("Neek", 34)
        println("my name is ${person.name}")
        println("my name is ${person.age}")
    }
}
```

Tried to include main() within in a class, I get following error.

```
warning: parameter 'args' is never used
    fun main(args : Array<String>) {
no main manifest attribute
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kotlin as a language doesn't enforce that you go OOP. Java is one of the only ones that actually makes you wrap everything you do inside of a class.

You can actually write all of your code at the file level in Kotlin across multiple different files. No classes needed.

If you decompile the code and look at it, what's happening in the file where you've declared

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {..}
```

is that it's being wrapped in a class that has the same name as the file that it's in.

If you have the above code in a file called Foo.kt, this is what's actually being generated

```
class FooKt {

     public static void main(String[] args) { }
}
```

Where the name of the class is the name of the file + "Kt"

Comment: Understood that OOP and procedural approaches can be grouped together. But what is the advantage of allowing this ?

Comment: Just that it doesn't force you to pick one way or another. It's up to you to leverage the tool how you wish. For example, you can (you actually can) decide to just use Kotlin for scripting

Answer (score 12):

You can write the `main` method on a Kotlin class, it has to be inside the `companion object`

```
class SuperCoolProgram {

    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            println("Hello Super Cool Program")
        }
    }

}
```

Static methods can only be written inside the `companion object` because it is the only static

Answer (score 1):

**main** method and the other methods need to inside the **companion** object block

```kotlin
class TestMainMethod {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        fun main(args: Array<String>) {
            testFunc()
        }

        fun testFunc() {
        }
    }
}
```